# How to manage state in Angular using services and BehaviorSubject?

Tags: angular, service, ngrx, behaviorsubject

I don't know NgRx yet and I need to manage state in an Angular app,
the app is pretty simple, we have list of items, when user goes to items list I download that data and show it, but when user navigates to admin page and then comes back to items list component I don't want to download items list again. Can I manage state in Angular using services and BehaviorSubject? And what is the easiest way to manage state in simple Angular application (if it's possible without using NgRx)?

Comment: That should be handled by the effect. The component just dispatches the LoadData effect. Within the effect you check the state. If state has data, then dispatch LoadDataSkipped. If state needs data, call the api and dispatch LoadDataSuccess or LoadDataError.depending on the api's response.

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm thank you, could you give some links to tutorials with some examples?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to use an BehaviorSubject to store the data or do you want to use a global state like NgRx store? These are two different things. Nevertheless from your question I assume that you want to use a service for this.

You can just create a simple service for this:

```
@Injectable()
export class ItemService {
  items$ = this.loadItems().pipe(shareReplay());
}
```

This will result in `loadItems()` (the function where the HTTP observable will be returned) gets called only for the first subscription to this observable. After that new subscribers will receive the latest value from it.

After that you can inject this service in other components and use the `async` pipe to subscribe to the `items$` observable.

Comment: I want to use it as a store

Comment: You do you mean with „as a store“? Are you talking about NgRx store? In your question it‘s stated that you want to avoid NgRx.

Comment: I just wanted to keep the data in the service so that when the user navigates away from the component and comes back again I don't download the data again

Comment: Well, then you can just use my approach. You should then include this service in the providers array of app.module or set `@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})` to the service. It will keep the data for the lifetime of the application (until you reload or close your browser window).

Answer (score 1):

You can use it like this for immutable state:

```
    private readonly _someStateObj: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>('initial default value');
    public someStateObj: Observable<any> = this._someStateObj.asObservable();
```

To get the current value use:

```
get currentValueOfStateObj(): any {
    return this._someStateObj.value;
}
```

Use this to emit new values in the store (service) file:

```
this._someStateObj.next(area);
```

In the components you can inject the services and subscribe to someStateObj or get it's current value with the getter. If you do not need to hold state but only need to emit values use Subject instead.

Comment: Can you explain why this represents **immutable** state?

Comment: Because you cannot change the state directly from outside the store (service) file. You can only update it with the private readonly property inside the store.

Comment: I am not sure if immutable is the correct description in this case. I think calling it a private or hidden state store would be more suitable, because the actual state is not necessarily immutable. Of course in your example a string is used, which is an immutable primitive by default, but other types aren‘t.

Comment: True, but editing the object received from the getter will not update the value inside the behaviorSubject and thus not for the return value of the getter. Even if its and array, object or some nested objects and or arrays.

The only way to update the value of the getter and behavior subject is by calling .next() and this can only be done inside the store.

Comment: This is actually not correct. Let's say you define a your "state" like `state = new BehaviorSubject({ testValue: 1 });`, and then you define the following: `this.state.subscribe((val) => {
      val.testValue = 2;
      console.log(this.state.value);
    });`. In the log you will see that the actual value of the behaviorsubject has changed. Immutability has to be enforced by the developer.

Comment: Yeah but in your scenario you subscribe to the behaviorSubject, in my code you subscribe to the Observable. If you subscribe to this in a component you can update the values without changes the value of the behaviorSubject. And because the behaviorSubject is a prive readonly you cannot access it from components

Comment: This is also not. You will still be able to change the actual value of the BehaviorSubject, even if you subscribe to it using `.asObservable`. The reason is that the reference to the object contained in `.value` is passed to the subscribers. There is no function in place where some `deep` copy is made of the value before passing it to the subscribers.

Comment: You are correct, you should use Object.Freeze or structuredclone or something to make the value immutable as well. My bad :)